# failed to init recognizer java.io.FileNotFoundException sync/assets.lst - pocketsphinx

Tags: android, pocketsphinx

I want to use [pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid).

when I run my model I got this error :

> failed to init recognizer java.io.FileNotFoundException 
>   sync/assets.lst

but inside my asset there isn't this file (`assets.lst`):

[image]

I don't understand this section of article :

> http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid#including_resource_files
>
> ```
> Copy app/asset.xml build file from demo application into your application into same folder app.
> Edit app/build.gradle build file to run assets.xml, just as in android demo:
> ```

I'm using android studio and I have not `app` directory in my model .

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of your entire project structure - you should have the app folder. Let us see your project folder structure to confirm.

Comment: Is there `app ` directory for each `model ` or each `project` ?

Comment: You should have `app` directory for the project - and this is where the application's source code will be located.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by manually cleaning up /HelloWorld/app/build.gradle to include all dependencies. File is,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.blepsias.speakeasy"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
}
dependencies {
implementation project(':pocketsphinx')
implementation project(':models')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

The previous file that was causing the failed-to-init error was generated by Android Studio had other stuff and was missing the pocketsphinx.aar reference. Lots of ways to skin this cat most likely...

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. create a folder called `sync` on `app/src/main/assets`
2. copy your created language model (https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm/) or all the content of sync folder in demo project which is located at : `models/src/main/assets/sync` to the created folder on step one on your project.
3. add the following lines to your `app/build.gradle` :

   `ant.importBuild 'assets.xml'
   preBuild.dependsOn(list, checksum)
   clean.dependsOn(clean_assets)`
4. sync your gradle and run your project with codes provided from demo